# Не понятно поведение api discord.js

Tags: node.js, консоль, бот, discord-api

Пишу бота для дискорда. На своём сервере я могу с помощью бота перечислить никнеймы всех участников сервера с помощью этого кода:

```
client.guilds.get('guildID').members.forEach(elem => {
    console.log(`${elem.nickname}, ${elem.user.username}`);
});
```

`elem.nickaname` - никнейм, который дали пользователю на сервере

`elem.user.username` - никнейм, который указан у пользователя в профиле. (устанавливается при регистрации)

Исполнение данного кода приводит к выводу следующей информации в консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некоторые имена отображаются как `null`. Это имя - важная часть моей задумки, которую я хочу воплотить. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема в том, что у пользоватей, чьё имя отображено как `null` - не установлен отдельный никнейм для сервера.